# Flow of a program not going inside if condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function monthassign()
{
    document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex=0;


}
function isleap()
{
    var yr=document.getElementById("year").value;
    if ((parseInt(yr)%4) == 0)
    {
      if (parseInt(yr)%100 == 0)
      {
        if (parseInt(yr)%400 != 0)
        {
        //alert("Not Leap");
        return "false";
        }
        if (parseInt(yr)%400 == 0)
        {
        //alert("Leap");
        return "true";
        }
      }
      if (parseInt(yr)%100 != 0)
      {
        //alert("Leap");
        return "true";
      }
    }
    if ((parseInt(yr)%4) != 0)
    {
        //alert("Not Leap");
        return "false";
    } 
}

function dateassign()
{
    var yr=isleap();

    var mth=parseInt(document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex);
    var dt=document.getElementById("date")

    if(yr)
    {
        if(mth==2)
        {   
            //alert(yr);
            dt.options.length = 0;
            for(i=1; i<30; i++)
            {   
                dt.add(new Option(i,i), null) //add new option to end of "date"
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    if(yr==false && mth==2)
    {
        //alert("Second fun");
        dt.options.length = 0;
        for(i=1; i<29; i++)
        {   
            dt.add(new Option(i,i), null) //add new option to end of "date"
        }
        return; 
    }

    if(mth==4 || mth==6 || mth==9 || mth==11)
    {
        dt.options.length = 0;
        for(i=1; i<31; i++)
        {   
            dt.add(new Option(i,i), null) //add new option to end of "date"
        }
        return; 
    }
    else
    {
        dt.options.length = 0;
        for(i=1; i<32; i++)
        {   
            dt.add(new Option(i,i), null) //add new option to end of "date"
        }
        return; 
    }
}   
</script>
```

My problem is when the variable yr contains false value the first if condition gets executed in `function dateassign()`. When the yr contains false value it is expected to shift the program control to the code block `if(yr==false && mth==2)`, but it's not happening. I'm fed up of this problem of execution of specific condition even if the condition is false and why the control is not going inside a specific if condition. Please help me out of this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are so many problems with this code I don't even know where to begin... I guess you could start by looking up how `if..else` statements work, and from there move on to learning how to declare variables in JS.

Comment: The flow starts with the call to dateassign() function and the problem persists in the same function's if condition.@zzzzBov

Comment: @Mate. Thanks you are absolutely right. After removing of "" around true and false it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`true` and `false` are not the same thing as `"true"` and `"false"`. The first is a Boolean, but the second is a string. You should be returning Boolean values, so you'll need to replace each instance of `"true"` with `true` and `"false"` with `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Waleed Khan for your help. I didn't notice the thing you observer. After removing the double quotes aroud true and false the function is working fine. Thanks again.